# convergence of $\sum_{n}^{\infty}(-1)^n \log(1+\sin(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I found that series $\sum_{n}^{\infty}(-1)^n \log(1+\sin(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$ is not absolutely convergent, but $\lim a_n = 0$, so I suspect that this series could converge, I want to use Leibniz test, but I don't know how to prove than the sequence is not increasing. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln(1+x)$ is increasing for positive $x$, $sin(x)$ is increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$ so all you need to show is that the sequence $(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$ is non increasing (and takes values in $[0, \pi/2]$). do you know how to do that?

Comment: yes I think i got it, I can simply prove if this inequality is true right? $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\ge\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}$ And since it is not increasing and $a_1<\pi /2 $ I can conclude it is in that interval and therefore the series converge not absolutely.

Comment: yep, that's all you need (although you have a typo there, should be $ \sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}$